# How to filter decreasing element in an increasing vector?

Tags: clojure, filtering, series

For example

```
[1 2 3 40 7 30 31 32 41]
```

after filtering should be

```
[1 2 3 30 31 32 41]
```

The problem doesn't seem very simple because I'd like to maximize the size of the resulting vector, so that if the starting vector is

```
[1 2 3 40 30 31 32 41 29]
```

I prefer this result

```
[1 2 3 30 31 32 41]
```

than just

```
[1 2 3 29]
```

Comment: The naive solution: generate all permutations of all positions that must be skipped, then check if it maintains the required property, then pick the longest. The number of permutations is obviously `2^N` in this case and it's just 512 for the `[1 2 3 40 30 31 32 41 29]`

Comment: a brute force approach won't work here because my series are formed by hundreds of elements. I can consider heuristics.

Comment: Then at first glance the approaches from dynamic programming might be applied.

Comment: I don't understand the first output example. If you just remove `40` you'd have a strictly increasing vector which is larger than your example.

Comment: @Andre you are right, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is known as the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

Via [rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Clojure):

```
(defn place [piles card]
  (let [[les gts] (->> piles (split-with #(<= (ffirst %) card)))
        newelem (cons card (->> les last first))
        modpile (cons newelem (first gts))]
    (concat les (cons modpile (rest gts)))))

(defn a-longest [cards]
  (let [piles (reduce place '() cards)]
    (->> piles last first reverse)))

(a-longest [1 2 3 40 30 31 32 41 29])
;; => (1 2 3 30 31 32 41)
```

Could probably be optimized to use `transients` if you care about performance.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i am looking for